# node.js how to stream 22GB gzipped file uncompress on the fly

Tags: node.js, stream, gunzip

I need to iterate over the lines in a 22GB gzipped file. Expanded, the file is 250GB.(It's the [Google Freebase db dump](https://developers.google.com/freebase/data))

I'm not too savvy with streams. Is there a way to stream the file and gunzip it as I go?

Here is going the other way:

```
var r = fs.createReadStream('file.txt');
var z = zlib.createGzip();
var w = fs.createWriteStream('file.txt.gz');
r.pipe(z).pipe(w);
```

Comment: that is a **massive** amount of data; normally that much data is really only used in media systems (music, video) which can be *CO*mpressed and *DEC*ompressed using an industry standard process (CODEC).  What kind of data do you need to stream that is that large?

Comment: It's the Google Freebase dump. It only comes in one size.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is the reverse operation using `zlib.createGunzip` instead of `zlib.createGzip`:

```
var r = fs.createReadStream('file.txt.gz');
var z = zlib.createGunzip();
var w = fs.createWriteStream('file.txt');
r.pipe(z).pipe(w);
```

Comment: Thank you - one last thing: how would I limit this to first 1000 rows?